# Angular 8 - Videos are not playing in lighbox

Tags: angular, lightbox

I am able to show images in lightbox

But when trying to play video in ngx-lighbox. But it is not working. Also not getting any error

I have used reference from below link

https://therichpost.com/angular-9-angular-ngx-lightbox/

Code:
**Html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let image of _albums; let i=index">
  <img [src]="image.thumb" (click)="open(i)" />
</div>

 typescript:
 _albums = [];
  constructor(private _lightbox: Lightbox) {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      const src = 'https://themyth92.com/project/ngx-lightbox/demo/img/image' + i + '.jpg';
      const caption = 'Image ' + i + ' caption here';
      const thumb = 'https://themyth92.com/project/ngx-lightbox/demo/img/image' + i + '-thumb.jpg';
      const album = {
         src: src,
         caption: caption,
         thumb: thumb
      };
 
      this._albums.push(album);
    }
  }
 
  open(index: number): void {
    // open lightbox
    this._lightbox.open(this._albums, index);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this snippet

```
this.lightbox.opened.subscribe(res => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const video: HTMLMediaElement = document.querySelector("#lightbox-video-gallery .g-active-item video");
    if(video) {
      video.play();
    }
  });
});
```

You can also checkout this library https://www.positronx.io/angular-video-player-using-ngx-videogular-with-customized-controls-example/.

Comment: Thanks Jaypal for your reply. Getting below error

 Property 'opened' does not exist on type 'Lightbox'. Did you mean 'open'?

Comment: Yes Please try with open property, and also checkout this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-litty-lightbox?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts     and this one as well https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-embed-video-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Getting this error: TS2339 (TS) Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(album: IAlbum[], curIndex?: number, options?: {}) => void'.

Comment: this would definitely help you , https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-gallery-xe4tu6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhome%2Fhome.component.ts

Comment: This snippet is complete nonsense. I don't know what you are using but it is not ngx-lightbox which this question is about.

Comment: This answer is grabbed from a Github issue for a completely different library: https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-gallery/issues/304 .